Delete a video of a test suite execution that was uploaded to Vimeo from testRigor
For exploration purposes, I created and executed a test suite from my testRigor account. Now, the executed test suite is public and visible for public in Vimeo account. Please advise on how to delete the video uploaded from testRigor to Vimeo.
I attempted to delete the public video in Vimeo account from my end, but there is no delete option available. Additionally, I raised an IT request, but received no response.

I want to delete few public test case associated with it. As the account when I used was public version I don't have any option to delete the test cases . Please provide me the solution

It's best to make that type of request in the chat available when you log in between 8am and 5pm PST. If the request is made outside of that time, the request becomes a ticket that they see later. They will get to that request as well, but it's always best during the PST work hours for fastest response.

I want to delete few public test case associated with it. As the account when I used was public version I don't have any option to delete the test cases . Please provide me the solution
